# Importing Lilypond file into a local music21 corpus

Tags: python, lilypond, music21

I'm hoping to run a corpus study on some local Lilypond (.ly) files, but I'm having trouble importing them into a local music21 corpus.

I can only assume the answer is on the [music21.converter](https://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleConverter.html#music21.converter.parse) page, but I somehow can't seem to untangle it. As suggested at the top of that page, I have tried:

```
converter.parse('/home/richard/test.ly')
```

Only to receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/richard/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/__init__.py", line 1168, in parse
    return parseFile(valueStr, number=number, format=m21Format,
  File "/home/richard/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/__init__.py", line 1027, in parseFile
    v.parseFile(fp, number=number, format=format, forceSource=forceSource, **keywords)
  File "/home/richard/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/__init__.py", line 548, in parseFile
    useFormat = self.getFormatFromFileExtension(fp)
  File "/home/richard/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/music21/converter/__init__.py", line 526, in getFormatFromFileExtension
    raise ConverterFileException(f'cannot find a format extensions for: {fp}')
music21.converter.ConverterFileException: cannot find a format extensions for: /home/richard/test.ly
```

Can anyone clarify the proper way to import these .ly files? I'm unfortunately new to Python, so I'm afraid I don't entirely know what I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Music21 does not import Lilypond files, only export.  Because `.ly` files are essentially Scheme code with macros, it is extremely hard to import for any program not itself written in Scheme.  See https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42315/lilypond-to-musicxml-to-sibelius for some options.  The best one I've found is to use an older version of Frescobaldi.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I was hoping you'd respond. For now I used Lilypond to generate a midi, and then I was able to convert the midi. Are you aware of any potential problems with that approach?

Comment: you're likely to lose thing like exact spelling of notes (G# vs Ab, etc.) but it will work otherwise